# Alternative to CurrentManagedThreadId that is constant across await?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await, .net-4.5

In my C# logging classes, I display `CurrentManagedThreadId` in the log output so that it's possible to follow a specific thread of execution. I also use the thread ID as a unique key to manage per-thread indentation levels (to show nesting in trace output).

I only just realized that `await` doesn't always return on the same thread. I'm not sure why I didn't notice this before, but I'm certainly seeing it now when I run my WinRT unit tests.

Is there some kind of "logical-thread-id" ("context-id"?) that is unique (among concurrently running threads), and constant across awaited method calls?

I'm developing for both .NET Framework (desktop) and WinRT Win8/8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

If you want to track a causality stack on WinRT, your only real option is to modify every `await` in your application as described [in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx).

You have more options on the desktop. For example, my [async diagnostics library](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) uses PostSharp in combination with the `LogicalCallStack` (a technique I [describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html)) to track causality stacks for you.